# Read a tiff file's dimension and resolution without loading it first

Tags: c#, memory, tiff

How to read a tiff file's dimension (width and height) and resolution (horizontal and vertical) without first loading it into memory by using code like the following.  It is too slow for big files and I don't need to manipulate them.

```
Image tif = Image.FromFile(@"C:\large_size.tif");
float width = tif.PhysicalDimension.Width;
float height = tif.PhysicalDimension.Height;
float hresolution = tif.HorizontalResolution;
float vresolution = tif.VerticalResolution;
tif.Dispose();
```

Edit:

Those tiff files are Bilevel and have a dimension of 30x42 inch.  The file sizes are about 1~2 MB.  So the method above works Ok but slow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ran into this myself and found the solution (possibly here). `Image.FromStream` with `validateImageData = false` allows you access to the information you're looking for, without loading the whole file.

```
using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\large_size.tif", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  using(Image tif = Image.FromStream(stream, false, false))
  {
    float width = tif.PhysicalDimension.Width;
    float height = tif.PhysicalDimension.Height;
    float hresolution = tif.HorizontalResolution;
    float vresolution = tif.VerticalResolution;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just saw your comments.  I tried and you are right.  The method is much faster than the one used in my original question.  Thanks.

Comment: Where is this `Image` from?

Comment: System.Drawing.Image

Comment: Why use "tif.PhysicalDimension.Width" instead of "tif.Width" ?

Comment: @Maxter, `Image.Width` is always pixels. `Image.PhysicalDimension` may have different units depending on the image type.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, all classes from System.Drawing namespace load image data immediately when image is open.

I think [LibTiff.Net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff) can help you to read image properties without loading image data. It's free and open-source (BSD license, suitable for commercial applications).

Here is a sample for your task (error checks are omitted for brevity):

```
using BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic;

namespace ReadTiffDimensions
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Tiff image = Tiff.Open(args[0], "r"))
            {
                FieldValue[] value = image.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH);
                int width = value[0].ToInt();

                value = image.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH);
                int height = value[0].ToInt();

                value = image.GetField(TiffTag.XRESOLUTION);
                float dpiX = value[0].ToFloat();

                value = image.GetField(TiffTag.YRESOLUTION);
                float dpiY = value[0].ToFloat();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of the library.

Comment: Thanks for presenting the code.  I think LibTiff.Net is probably the only open-source choice out there for non-commercial use.  My program is a tiny single program of less than 30k.  Processing tiff files is not its main task.  So right now I prefer just stick with my current slow but simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://blog.bee-eee.com/2008/03/20/c-reading-tiff-using-libtiff/), it seems to be what you are looking for. Just skip everything after:

```
TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, ref w); //your width
TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, ref h); //your height
TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, ref bits);
TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, ref samples);
```

Don't forget to close after you:

```
TIFFClose(tif);
```

Comment: I found a partial solution of using Shell32.Folder.GetDetailsOf(). But it can only get dimension but not resolution on Windows XP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is reading the tiff binary header.

Here you can download the specification: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/tiff/index.html

Here is some code used to read Tiffs that you can use to learn:
http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidF6632006F25B8E5B3BCC62D13076B38D71847929.aspx?s=zoom

I created a library to read the tiff headers some time ago (with this two resources as base) but it was part of my employer code so I can't post my code here and I can say it is no really hard.

I Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.  I have roughly read materials on both links.  But right now I am hesitated to spend time to create the solution from scratch, because I don't have much experience on programming on bit-to-bit level.

Comment: I will try WPF Imaging Component for this before finishing the project.  I probably will use information you provided to code a solution for exercise on my own time.