# How to find the Tif Image Pixel ratio in C#

Tags: c#, pixel, tiff

I have a Tif image which has been stretched meaning that its scale ratio for a pixel is not a square pixel How can I find the scale ratio of a pixel using C# and correct the image to lose the extra stretch?

Comment: I think you want to find out the scale ratio of the image. Because you are asking for scale ratio of a pixel instead.

Comment: all I want to make sure that the pixel height and width are the same mean the pixel is square in value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048185/read-a-tiff-files-dimension-and-resolution-without-loading-it-first

Comment: So let me see if I understand. You want to get the ratio of the original image, so you can stretch it taking in consideration the original ratio, right?

Comment: I have being given an tiff image that being saved and for some reason after the image is saved when I open it, it is stretch horizontally I want to find the hight of a single pixel and change the width of the pixel to match the hight to be a square pixel and not streched pixel. I want to know if there is away i can find the information about the pixel and change it

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by calculating scale of Image width and height devided by the resolution ratio. [Posted by mikeTheLiar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048185/read-a-tiff-files-dimension-and-resolution-without-loading-it-first)